# Option Pricing using Monte Carlo Algo

Tags: performance, cuda, opencl, gpu

I have to use Monte Carlo Algorithm for Option pricing on GPU. I have two choices: one is CUDA on NVIDIA GPUs, another is OpenCL. I am confused which API should I use. I know that development on OpenCl might take more time as compared to CUDA, but as I am more concerned about the performance, I am wondering which way should I go and why?

Comment: For reference there are a variety of monte carlo and option pricing sample codes in the cuda [samples](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html) in both the [finance section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#finance) and the [libraries section](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cudalibraries)

Comment: @RobertCrovella, thanks, but I just need to know which way should I go, OpenCL or CUDA? I do not need portable solution, so does that mean I must go with CUDA? Will the performance will be better with CUDA than openCL?

Answer (score 3):

CUDA and OpenCL are two different platforms for programming GPUs. OpenCL is an **open standard** for **heterogeneous** platform like Cpu, Gpu,... while CUDA is **specific** to **NVIDIA GPUs**. 
As an engineering rule of thumb, if you want portability go ahead with OpenCL. If you want performance go ahead with CUDA.

You can find more about their perofrmance in the following references:

- [Coding Gorilla](http://codinggorilla.domemtech.com/?p=1135) blog: It shows the performance of two platforms
  for some sample applications.
- [A Comprehensive Performance Comparison of CUDA and OpenCL](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6047190&tag=1), by Jianbin Fang et. al. According to their studies it seems that **CUDA performs at most 30% better than OpenCL**.

Comment: I was wondering if there is a class of application where openCL excels CUDA?  The claim that "CUDA performs at most 30% better than OpenCL..." is valid for all type of applications or only for a particular class of applications?

Comment: @gpuguy: They benchmarked on many kinds of applications like: Graph traversal, linear algebra, spectral methods,...: This is the slide of the mentioned paper: http://www.ece.umn.edu/~wxiao/ee5940/lecture10-1.pdf. It has the applications and performance